# Pass any-dimensional numpy array to Cython class

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to pass an `np.ndarray` from Python to instantiate a Cython class. However, I can't work out how to do it for an *any*-dimensional array. I'd like my .pyx interface to look like:

wrapper.pyx:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "myClass.h":
    cdef cppclass C_myClass "myClass":
        void myClass(np.float32_t*, int*, int)

cdef class array:
    cdef C_myClass* cython_class
    cdef int shape[8]  # max number of dimensions = 8
    cdef int ndim

    def __init__(self, np.ndarray[dtype=np.float32_t] numpy_array):
        self.ndim = numpy_array.ndim
        for dim in range(self.ndim):
            self.shape[dim] = numpy_array.shape[dim]
        self.cython_class = new C_myClass(&numpy_array[0], &self.shape[0], self.ndim)

    def __del__(self):
        del self.cython_class
```

Such that the class constructor can look like:

myClass.h:

```
myClass(float* array_, int* shape_, int ndim_);
```

Do any of you know how to handle an array of any dimensions within Cython, while still being able to get the array shape parameters (I don't want the user to have to flatten the array or pass in the array shapes themselves)?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct Cython type for "numpy array with any number of dimensions" (or indeed "typed memoryview with any number of dimensions").

Therefore, I suggest leaving the array argument to the constructor untyped and using the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) yourself.

The following code is untested, but should give you the right idea

```
from cpython.buffer cimport Py_buffer, PyObject_GetBuffer,  PyBUF_ND, PyBUF_FORMAT, PyBuffer_Release

...

def __init__(self, array):
    cdef Py_buffer buf

    # shape and ndim can be passed as before - they don't
    # need the array to be typed
    self.ndim = numpy_array.ndim
    for dim in range(self.ndim):
        self.shape[dim] = numpy_array.shape[dim]

    # Note that PyBUF_ND requires a C contiguous array. This looks
    # to be an implicit requirement of your C++ class that you
    # probably don't realize you have
    PyObject_GetBuffer(array, buf, PyBUF_ND | PyBUF_FORMAT)
    if not buf.format == "f":
        PyBuffer_Release(buf)
        raise TypeError("Numpy array must have dtype float32_t")
    self.cython_class = new C_myClass(<float32_t*>buf.buf, &self.shape[0], self.ndim)
```

You then need to make sure you release the buffer with `ByBuffer_Release`.
It isn't clear whether `C_myClass` copies the data or holds a pointer to it.

- if `C_myClass` copies the data then call `PyBuffer_release` straight away after constructing `self.cython_class`
- if `C_myClass` holds a reference to the data then call `PyBuffer_release` in the destructor after `self.cython_class` is deleted.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for your help. I'd spent ages pouring through Numpy, Scipy and cupy's source code to find where the actual linkage to C++ was to create a C++ array with the dimensions inferred from an array. Do you know whether this is what it's doing?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Do you mean "is this what CuPy is doing?" I don't think so - they don't look to use Py_Buffer much their code. This probably isn't the only solution though.